# Problem with simple animation

Tags: iphone, uianimation

I am using animation on a button click first time show a view and second ti me hide a view.
here is my code for hiding a view

```
-(IBAction)clickme
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];


    [view1 setAlpha:0.0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

similar code is there for showing the view.

But the problem arises when user click the button many times again and again....means i am using 2 seconds for my animation but if user presses the same button in during the animation then the output result is very bad.

I don't want to disable that button during the period of animation.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of whether there's an animation going on, and ignore the click if it is.

Declare an instance variable `BOOL animating;` in your class header, and initialise it to `NO` in your `init`.

Then,

```
-(IBAction)clickme
{
    if (animating) return;
    animating = YES;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    [view1 setAlpha:0.0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    if (context == self)
        animating = NO;
}
```

Comment: You're missing [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:...];. ;)

Comment: @hennes No, I don't think so, `[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];` means these messages are sent without explicitly setting the selector.

Comment: Are you sure? I always thought I needed to set those manually. Well, please excuse my inexperience.

Answer (score 2):

try to use + (void)setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:(BOOL)fromCurrentState:

```
-(IBAction)clickme
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];


    [view1 setAlpha:0.0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```